# iTMSTransporter "Error accessing file" after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: testflight, macos-catalina, fastlane, itmstransporter

After upgrading macOS to Catalina the HOME directory changed from `/Local/Users/jenkins` to `/Users/jenkins` and now `iTMSTransporter` is failing with the following error (clearly still referencing the old HOME directory):

```
<Equinox Log Thread - Equinox Container: 471f1643-7038-4059-ab8e-14636d149eec> ERROR: Resolver: Install error - org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore Exception's name: java.io.IOException, Exception's message: Error accessing file:/Local/Users/jenkins/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.4.11.jar
[2020-04-23 13:08:48 EDT] <main> ERROR: could not find the service with interface (com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService)
```

I stumbled on this issue via `fastlane` which I reinstalled. I've done a lot of searching and tried a lot of things, e.g. installed the new Transporter app from Mac App Store and ran it from there, updated to the latest Xcode.  No luck. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by deleting the following pesky file which had the invalid directory reference:

`./System/Volumes/Data/Users/jenkins/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/repository.xml`

I noticed `INFO: using cached repository.xml file` so I searched for that file.